# Listview item background color change

Tags: json, listview, android-listview

I want to change the list-view item background color without onitemclick() method. Because at first i've to check item data and based on that it will change the color . How should i do it ?

Comment: You want to change the background color of `ListView Item` when _CLICKED_ after check some conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if(items.get(position).getSomething().equals(Something){
             // If your condition fulfills then change background color
             listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(#55667788);
        }
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_counter, null);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        viewHolder.number = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
        viewHolder.row = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rel_row);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    currentModel = list.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(currentModel.getName());
    holder.number.setText(currentModel.getNumber());

    if(holder.name.equals("SOMETHING")){
         holder.row.setBackgroundColor("#55667788");
    }else{
         holder.row.setBackgroundColor("#000000");
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I want to change bg color without onItemClick() method . Because i've to check that any item is holding a specific data or not .

Comment: Thanks nadeem. I didn't solve but i got the problem, so it will overcome .